# How to choose multiple topics in firebase console?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm currently creating an app in android studio with fcm implemented. For sending push notifictations I use the firebase console (cloud messaging). 
I want to choose mutliple topics when I send out a push notification. I don't want to make the whole process twice, so I want to choose multiple topics.

But I can only choose one topic per message, how can I choose more than one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase console currently only allows sending messages to a single topic. It does not allow sending messages to multiple topics, nor sending to conditions.

If you need such functionality, you will have to send the messages by calling the [FCM API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics) for example with a condition like `'TopicA' in topics || 'TopicB' in topics`.

You might also want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for adding the feature to the console.

Comment: Thank you. I also saw this, but I also need to schedule my push notifications.

Comment: There is no way to send to multiple topics through the console. So you can either schedule to a single topic through the console, or build something yourself through the API.